# why overflow-x scroll does not allow scroll to the left only if the first scroll is to the left?

Tags: html, css, angular

```
 <div class="row justify-content-center  mob-view" >

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4" *ngFor="let slide of specialization">
          <div class="brower-box">
              
                <div class="brower-image"> </div>
             
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

```
    @media(max-width :768px){
         .mob-view{

                  min-width: 100%;
                  display: flex ;
                  flex-direction: row;
                  overflow-x: auto;
                  flex-wrap: nowrap ;   } }
```

In the HTML code given the ngFor loads a loop of about 31 elements into the div with class "brower-box" , which it loads correctly in every viewport across devices. But my requirement is to load it in mobile view so it can be scrolled left and right to view it .  i tried using flex and the overflow property as given in the CSS code.

*PROBLEM*

using flex and overflow provided me with what i want . But out of the 31 elements to be loaded  the loop only loaded the elements starting from the 16-th  it can be scrolled. Also at first i cannot swipe or scroll to the left side , as the element starts from the 16 i can only move right to the 17 , 18 elements respectively . I can also scroll to left from the 31-st back to the 16-th element ,Beyond which (from 16 to 1) i cannot scroll to view those. But inspection using Dev-tools of chrome showed that every element from 1 -31 is being loaded only i cannot scroll to view it. so can anyone please help me find what problem am i going through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem myself .Though it is a small issue ,it took almost a day to sort it out. someone may encounter this issue . so i am posting this.

making following changes in CSS fixed the issue

```
css

       @media(max-width :768px){
         .mob-view{

                  min-width: 100%;
                  display: flex ;
                  flex-direction: row;
                  overflow-x: auto;
                  flex-wrap: nowrap ;
                  justify-content: unset !important;   } }
```